# Xcode 8 simulator issue when rotating to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm experiencing a very strange simulator issue with Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a).
The simulator starts fine when launching in portrait, however if I rotate to landscape it displays weird. Consequently, any Xcode projects that I run also face the same issue.
Any idea how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

I've tried resetting the simulator contents & settings from the simulator menus, restarting the simulator etc. but to no avail.

EDIT: Restarted Mac, no change :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Xcode 8.0.  The issue is addressed in Xcode 8.1.  You can work around the problem by turning off "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" from the Debug menu.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I will try that out until I download Xcode 8.1.

Comment: Bret, there are no known issues like this with Xcode 9.0.1.  Please file a radar with specifics (and feel free to point me to it from here).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling Xcode 8.0